# different restrictions on employee record

Tags: network-programming

I want to make an employee record that inputs these members:

- Int I'd
- Char name
- Car gender
- Char phone number
- Char address
- Char salary

  1. ID must be unique and can take only digits
  2. Name must be alphabetic and can take only four spaces. Otherwise display a message
  3. Gender can only F And M
  4. Phone number can only digits and '-'. This short dash
  5. Salary also can take digits

Please, help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thats means? You didn't understand my question?

Comment: I just want to apply these checks..

Comment: I tried but nothing happens.. I don't know what to do .. All output is wrong

Comment: Fixed some spelling and formatting, Removed the initial greetings (irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

You can set conditions based on the type of value.
For example:

```
final int ids[25];
int position;
//in the getid function
public void getid()
{
int i=0;
int id[position]=scanf("%d",&id);
for(i=20;i<=0;i--){
if(id[position]==ids[i])
{
//then show the message
printf("Duplicate id");
}
}
else{
printf("Nice!!");
}
}
```